How to deploy .NET app with Angular18 SSR on Nginx
I am currently working on a project that was initially created using the .NET Core and Angular 18 template in Visual Studio. The project was originally set up as SPA. Recently, I decided to switch to SSR because of SEO and installed @angular/ssr.
The application runs perfectly on IIS when tested locally. However, upon deploying the application to an Nginx server, I encounter a 404 error.
Despite these steps, the application fails to load on Nginx, resulting in a 404 error. I suspect there might be a configuration issue with Nginx that is causing this problem.
Could you please provide guidance on resolving this issue? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.
This is Nginx configuration:

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name stage.testsite.com;

    return 301 https://stage.testsite.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name stage.testsite.com;


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/stage.testsite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/stage.testsite.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;  # Security best practices
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;    # Pre-generated DH parameters

    # Set the root directory for your stage app
    root /var/www/stage-site;
    index index.html;

    # Enable Gzip for better performance
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # Proxy requests to your .NET Core application on port 5187
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5153;  # The port where your .NET Core app is running
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Error handling
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
    location = /custom_50x.html {
        root /var/www/stage-site
    }
}




"The application runs perfectly on IIS when tested locally" - could you add more details about your local setup? Are you running ng serve?

I started the project only in VS on start and it automatically started background and frontend apps. I'm not sure what it's doing in the background, but I got the SSR app. I also noticed that when publishing there is no more ClientApp/dist folder, but it was not there when I published the project as SPA but it worked on Nginx with this configuration.
